# monogame - how do I distribute a lib / package with content?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-content-pipeline

I wrote a UI lib for a monogame hobby project I'm working on, and I want to distribute the UI code / lib as open source for others to enjoy.

My question is - what do I do with all the content that comes with the UI lib? (widget textures, effects, etc.)

Is there a standard way to create a monogame lib that also include content? Or do I need to include the content directory with the distribution files and ask the user to add it manually to his own project Content manager?

Thanks!

Comment: Adding it as separate content provides the opportunity to the end user to customize the textures right?

Comment: Yeah, but it adds another installation step. also, if user already have files with the same names they will collide, but this can be easily avoided with folder name-spacing. Anyway that's why I'm asking - I'm not sure what's the clean, recommended way to distribute it. Do you think the way is to add the content manager file + its folder? thanks

Comment: If your UI elements can be instantiated using textures of my own choice then I would add your library only (without the your resources). Thus provide the contents as sample or starting point as separate files.